# searching for object with custom id

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have a class that looks like this

```
@Data
@NodeEntity
public class StoryCharacter {
    @Index(unique = true)
    private String agnosticId;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "FAMILIAR_WITH")
    private Set<StoryCharacter> acquaintances;
}
```

I needed a custom ID that is not related to the default `long` id. So I introduced a field and set it as `index`.

But how to find the object by that id?

I wanted to do it like this

```
session.openSession().load(StoryCharacter.class, "custom_id")
```

but it fails with error that it must be `Long`. I assume that maybe I need to use `Filter` object for search by that id. Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a custom id the field has to be annotated with `@Id` instead of `@Index(unique=true)`. In cases you do not want to set the id manually, there is an option to provide a id generation strategy (more details [in the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#_id_generation_strategy).

You are seeing this error because Neo4j-OGM cannot determine what type your id field has and falls back to the standard `Long`. If you define your id as mentioned above, the `load` will work.

Comment: So I can create `@Id` field without need of `Long` id field? Because I thought that `long` id is required.

Comment: Exactly. If you take care of id handling in your application by yourself, Neo4j-OGM will use this instead of relying on the internal id.