# update node if exists

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I've got a simple domain that looks like this

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NodeEntity
public class StoryCharacter extends GraphObject {
    @Index(unique = true)
    private String agnosticId;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "FAMILIAR_WITH")
    private Set<StoryCharacter> acquaintances;

    @Labels
    private Set<String> labels = new HashSet<>();

    // Neo4j requires constructor
    public StoryCharacter() {}
}
```

And `GraphObject` looks like this

```
@Data
abstract class GraphObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

The process of saving and loading object looks like this

```
var session = req.require(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
try (var tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
    session.save(character);
    tx.commit();
}

try (var tx = session.beginTransaction(Type.READ_ONLY)) {
    Collection<StoryCharacter> lists = session.loadAll(StoryCharacter.class,
        AgnosticIdUtils.findByIdQuery(character.getAgnosticId()));
    tx.commit();

    return TPCollectionUtils.getFirstElement(lists);
}
```

To generate `angnosticId` I created listener that looks like this

```
public class AddCharacterIdListener extends EventListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onPreSave(Event event) {
        StoryCharacter storyCharacter = (StoryCharacter) event.getObject();
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(storyCharacter.getAgnosticId())) {
            var schema = TPCollectionUtils.getFirstElement(storyCharacter.getLabels());
            var id = AgnosticIdUtils.generateId(schema, storyCharacter.getName());
            storyCharacter.setAgnosticId(id);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I save the object it still creates it multiple times. In database I have multiple nodes that have the same `agnosticId`.

How to make it update the object instead of creating it again? I could probably generate `agnosticId` earlier and then search for object and then somehow merge it with the existing one...But is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this question has some relations to [searching for object with custom id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991177/searching-for-object-with-custom-id).

The `GraphObject` defines an `id` field that reflects the internal Neo4j id. If no custom id is defined, Neo4j-OGM will use this field to determine if an object is already in the database (has a positive id set) or not.

The `@Index(unique=true)` annotation is only a hint for Neo4j-OGM to create the index if the [auto index manager feature](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:indexing:creation) is set to a suitable value.

Comment: So if it find existing `id` then it will perform update (or merge)?

Comment: Yes. This is the only field Neo4j-OGM uses to determine if a node needs to get created or updated.